# How to Install CA Certificate on iOS devices in AWS Device Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

We have to install our CA certificates on end user iOS devices manually or pushed the certificates though MobileIron service for our users. After successful installation of CA Certificates only, our App Users can benefit our services.

As of now i don’t see any option to install CA Certificates on iOS device which is located in AWS Device Farm before running my appium tests.

is there any way to to add and active certificate?

Answer (score 0):

> We have to install our CA certificates on end user iOS devices manually

Can you use remote access for testing? You should be able to manually interact with devices. Though admittedly not sure of what is required to install a certificate. I would be worried about the relatively thin cleanup process Device Farm does.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/post-test-and-cleanup.html

> Note
>   It is possible for data to persist between sessions in some cases, especially if you make use of the device system outside the context of your app. For this reason, and because Device Farm captures video and logs of activity taking place during your use of each device, we recommend that you do not enter sensitive information (for example, Google account or Apple ID), personal information, and other security-sensitive details during your automated test and remote access sessions.

This [article](https://support.n4l.co.nz/s/article/Installing-an-SSL-Certificate-on-an-iOS-Device-Manually) suggests that this would need to be done using the settings app. If automation is needed then the Appium tests can automate the settings app as discussed in this other article(not tested).
https://appiumpro.com/editions/66

Answer (score 0):

I believe the latest appium xcuitest driver has released support for installing certificates on iOS devices provided you have certain command line tools installed.

https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#mobile-installcertificate